# How can I access to all final field in a class with for

Tags: java, for-loop, dynamic, get, final

I want to use for and access all final field (public) in a class.
ex:

```
String finalFieldOfMath="";
for (String s: Math)
  finalFieldOfMath+= s+", ";
```

thanks

Comment: You're looking for Reflection.

Comment: The example that I wrote is just an example.
There is a class with lots of field final.
each field present a column in DataBase.
I want have all of the final value to create the data base.
EX: 
`nameOfClass.data1 = "ID";
nameOfClass.data2 = "Name";
...`

Comment: You're still looking for Reflection.